# Is it grammatically correct to seperate a complete sentence and an incomplete sentence with a semi-colon?

Tags: semicolons

A common pattern in English is to separate two complete sentences with a semi-colon.

For example,

> John was hurt; he knew she only said it to upset him.

"John was hurt" is a complete sentence, and so is, "he knew she only said it to upset him."

The pattern is:

> [sentence] [semi-colon] [sentence]

As you know, we usually use a semi-colon, instead of a period, when it is important to take the two sentences together to form the whole idea.

However, in what cases (if any) is the following pattern valid?

> [complete sentence] [semi-colon] [incomplete sentence]

Examples:

> They’re not very expensive; maybe $10.
>   Both are unconscious; no clear prognosis.

Comment: "Seperate" is missing a rat.

Answer (score 2):

The venerable Warriner's English Grammar and Composition regards the examples in which an incomplete clause follows the semicolon as incorrect.  According to Warriner, a semicolon may join two independent clauses, both of which should be possessed of a subject and verb.

Answer (score -1):

If the sentence fragment would be considered stylistically acceptable on its own, then using a semicolon wouldn't be obviously wrong.

For instance:

> "How much do they cost?"
> "Maybe $10."

---

*Maybe $10*, even though it's a sentence fragment and would not be acceptable as a standalone sentence, is acceptable in that dialogue exchange.

An expanded version could be considered in the same light:

> "How much do they cost?"
> "They're not very expensive; maybe $10."

If the fragment is okay on its own as a reply, I would argue that the longer version, with the semicolon, shouldn't be immediately ruled out.

---

However, this still remains a matter of style. (Style overruling conventional use in this particular context.)  It might simply *look* strange to use a semicolon in this situation—regardless of whatever reasoning that says it should be okay or at least not immediately wrong.

It's probably more common to use a dash or an actual period:

> "How much do they cost?"
> "They're not very expensive—maybe $10."
>
> "How much do they cost?"
> "They're not very expensive. Maybe $10."

---

So, in terms of style, first determine if the sentence fragment can actually be used at all. (And that would depend on style guides, the audience, and your personal opinion.) Once that's determined, decide which punctuation looks best.

But, as a matter of style, this is subjective.